# flutter: My last data is hiding behind the navigation bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

### in redmi note 8 pro I got Bottom RenderFlex overflowed by 84 pixels. And My last data is hiding behind the navigation bar.

in redmi note 8 pro I got Bottom RenderFlex overflowed by 84 pixels. And My last data is hiding behind the navigation bar.

[image]

in redmi 4. It looks like it
[image]

This is my event section code

```
import 'package:cwc/constants/top_card.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/activities.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_page_changer.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_tab_view.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Home/components/search_components.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Home/home_page.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/footer/bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/footer/bottom_nav_bar_event.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Event extends StatefulWidget {
  const Event({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EventState createState() => _EventState();
}

class _EventState extends State<Event> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff80CAD7),
      body: SafeArea(

        child: Column(
          children: [
            TopCard(),

            Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0)),
                ),
                child: EventTab())
            // EventPageChanger(),
            // Expanded(child: Activities()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
        },
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        child: Image.asset('assets/btnavico.png'),
        elevation: 5.0,
        highlightElevation: 10,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (10 / 100),
          child: BottomNavBarEvent()),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my event tab secion code

```
import 'package:cwc/ui/CwcTv/components/slides/slide_component.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/CwcTv/components/videos/video_component.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/CwcTv/cwc_tv.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/activities.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/category_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class EventTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EventTabState createState() => _EventTabState();
}

class _EventTabState extends State<EventTab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin, WidgetsBindingObserver {
  TabController? controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: 4, vsync: this);
    controller!.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.removeObserver(this);
    controller?.dispose();
  }

  void _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _tabSection(context, controller!),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Widget _tabSection(BuildContext context, TabController controller) {
  return DefaultTabController(
    length: 4,
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 10, 14, 0),
              child: TabBar(
                controller: controller,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 66,
                        height: 32,
                        color: controller.index == 0
                            ? Color(0xff158998)
                            : Color(0xffF1F2F6),
                        // decoration: const BoxDecoration(

                        //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        // ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'All',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: controller.index == 0
                                  ? Color(0xffffffff)
                                  : Color(0xff8F9698),
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 85,
                        height: 32,
                        color: controller.index == 1
                            ? Color(0xff158998)
                            : Color(0xffF1F2F6),
                        // decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        //   color: Color(0xffF1F2F6),
                        //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        // ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Category',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: controller.index == 1
                                  ? Color(0xffffffff)
                                  : Color(0xff8F9698),
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 85,
                        height: 32,
                        color: controller.index == 2
                            ? Color(0xff158998)
                            : Color(0xffF1F2F6),
                        // decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        //   color: Color(0xffF1F2F6),
                        //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        // ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Upcoming',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: controller.index == 2
                                  ? Color(0xffffffff)
                                  : Color(0xff8F9698),
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 66,
                        height: 32,
                        color: controller.index == 3
                            ? Color(0xff158998)
                            : Color(0xffF1F2F6),
                        // decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        //   color: Color(0xffF1F2F6),
                        //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        // ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Free',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: controller.index == 3
                                  ? Color(0xffffffff)
                                  : Color(0xff8F9698),
                              fontSize: 12,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (50 / 100),
              child:  TabBarView(controller: controller,
                children: const [
                  Activities(),
                  CategoryPage(),
                  Activities(),
                  Activities(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Wrap your `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView` refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69392879/13997210) for that hope its helpful to you

Comment: The question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @hman_codes actually I used TabBar in middle that TabBarView is not responsive

Answer (score 1):

wrap the column widget into singalchildscrollview widget

```
 body: SafeArea(
singlechildscrollview(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TopCard(),
       ],
       ),
       ),
```

Answer (score 0):

try the code down below

```
import 'package:cwc/constants/top_card.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/activities.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_page_changer.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Event/components/event_tab_view.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Home/components/search_components.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/Home/home_page.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/footer/bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:cwc/ui/footer/bottom_nav_bar_event.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class Event extends StatefulWidget {
  const Event({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EventState createState() => _EventState();
}

class _EventState extends State<Event> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff80CAD7),
      body: SafeArea(

        child: body: SingleChildScrollView(
   child:Column(
     children:[
            TopCard(),

            Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0)),
                ),
                child: EventTab())
            // EventPageChanger(),
            // Expanded(child: Activities()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
        },
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        child: Image.asset('assets/btnavico.png'),
        elevation: 5.0,
        highlightElevation: 10,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (10 / 100),
          child: BottomNavBarEvent()),
    );
  }
}
```

i just wrap the column with `SingleChildScrollView`
hope it will fix the problem