# How to make a page vertically scrollable in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I have made a dashboard page in flutter for a shopping app. I have written my code inside column but due to that the code is not scrollable and pixels keep overflowing. I have tried using ListView instead of column and I have also tried Using column inside ListView but as I try this both the output of the whole page disappears.

This is the snippet of the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwmWf.png)

Comment: Please share code instead of sharing the images of code.

Comment: Try to add your `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView` refer my answers for more [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68646487/13997210), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69392879/13997210)

Comment: @SunderamDubey Sorry for the inconvenience there's a motive behind sharing the image and not the code as the code is too lengthy.

Comment: @BhavikDalal See how do I make a minimal reproductible example [repro].

Comment: @SunderamDubey I will check this out.

Comment: How about `SingleChildWidget`?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil as soon as I am adding any thing other than column the output gets disappeared.

Comment: Check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Widget Tree like this:

`SingleChildScrollView -> Column -> Expanded (one of the many Childs)`

it will probably generate an error because `Expanded` is trying to expand to fill as much space as it can, and `SingleChildScrollView` gives all needed space (vertically, in this case) to his child. So it ends up with the `Expanded` widget trying to expand to infinite.

In order to fix this problem, you should programmatically calculate the height (the constraints) and wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` with a `ConstainedBox`.

**Follow this [guide](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html). It contains almost all cases.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try listview with shrinkwrap = true instead of using column

Answer (score 0):

Change all the expanded to container and assign them the height you need to adjust all the containers accordingly.
Then add all of your code in SingleChildScrollView and assign the direction you want to scroll you page in that is horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```dart
// OLD

Column(children: [ ... ])

// NEW

ListView( shrinkWrap:true, children: [ ... ])
```